# GemFire 8.2.0 embeded locator service

Tags: gemfire

I am trying to cluster servers in gemfire using an embedded locator service.

server 1

    `serverCache = new CacheFactory().set("cache-xml-file", "server-cache.xml")
    .set("mcast-port", "0")
    .set("start-locator", "11001")
    .set("locators", "localhost[11001],10.0.0.193[11002]").create();`

server 2

     `serverCache = new CacheFactory().set("cache-xml-file", "server-cache.xml")
    .set("mcast-port", "0")
    .set("start-locator", "11002")
    .set("locators", "10.0.0.192[11001],localhost[11002]").create();`

but they cant connect

from server 1

*[warn 2016/02/08 20:37:41.510 UTC  tid=0x28] Locator discovery task could not exchange locator information localhost[11001] with ip-10-0-0-193.ec2.internal[11002] after 55 retry attempts. Retrying in 10,000 ms.*

from server 2

*[warn 2016/02/08 20:46:27.867 UTC  tid=0x28] Locator discovery task could not exchange locator information localhost[11002] with ip-10-0-0-192.ec2.internal[11001] after 102 retry attempts. Retrying in 10,000 ms.*

it close but i am missing something

Yes, using the .set("bind-address", "10.0.0.193") answer seemed to do the trick.  just to comfirm on the logs,  did i make a cluster

server1

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:07.445 UTC  tid=0x3c] Membership: Processing addition < ip-10-0-0-192(14522):14968 >

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:07.445 UTC  tid=0x3c] Admitting member :14968>. Now there are 2 non-admin member(s).

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:07.460 UTC  tid=0x41] Member ip-10-0-0-192(14522):14968 is not equivalent or in the same redundancy zone.

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:12.923 UTC  tid=0x28] Locator discovery task exchanged locator information ip-10-0-0-193.ec2.internal[11001] with ip-10-0-0-192.ec2.internal[11001]: {-1=[ip-10-0-0-192.ec2.internal[11001], ip-10-0-0-193.ec2.internal[11001]]}.

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:13.245 UTC  tid=0x46] Initializing region _gfe_non_durable_client_with_id_ip-10-0-0-186(3936:loner):49683:5b2966c5_2_queue

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:13.247 UTC  tid=0x46] Initialization of region _gfe_non_durable_client_with_id_ip-10-0-0-186(3936:loner):49683:5b2966c5_2_queue completed

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:13.252 UTC  tid=0x46] Entry expiry tasks disabled because the queue became primary. Old messageTimeToLive was: 180

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:13.435 UTC  tid=0x46] Initializing region _gfe_non_durable_client_with_id_ip-10-0-0-189(4036:loner):51441:762a66c5_2_queue

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:13.437 UTC  tid=0x46] Initialization of region _gfe_non_durable_client_with_id_ip-10-0-0-189(4036:loner):51441:762a66c5_2_queue completed

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:13.438 UTC  tid=0x46] Entry expiry tasks disabled because the queue became primary. Old messageTimeToLive was: 180

and server 2

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:07.245 UTC  tid=0x1] Attempting to join distributed system whose membership coordinator is ip-10-0-0-193(16745):57474 using membership ID ip-10-0-0-192(14522):14968

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:07.408 UTC  tid=0x1] Membership: lead member is now ip-10-0-0-193(16745):57474

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:07.412 UTC  tid=0x23] GemFire failure detection is now monitoring ip-10-0-0-193(16745):57474

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:07.413 UTC  tid=0x1] Entered into membership with ID ip-10-0-0-192(14522):14968.

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:07.414 UTC  tid=0x1] Starting DistributionManager ip-10-0-0-192(14522):14968.  (took 272/ ms)

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:07.414 UTC  tid=0x1] Initial (membershipManager) view =  [ip-10-0-0-193(16745):57474{lead}, ip-10-0-0-192(14522):14968]

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:07.414 UTC  tid=0x1] Admitting member :57474>. Now there are 1 non-admin member(s).

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:07.414 UTC  tid=0x1] Admitting member :14968>. Now there are 2 non-admin member(s).

[info 2016/02/09 09:39:07.446 UTC :57474 shared unordered uid=1 port=39916> tid=0x28] Member ip-10-0-0-193(16745):57474 is not equivalent or in the same redundancy zone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the locator is binding to `localhost`, so you should set `bind-address` for each cache server with `set("bind-address", "10.0.0.192")`. Also obviously have your `locators` point at these addresses.

Comment: yes it seemed to do the trick.  I edited the question just to confirm I did make a GemFire cluster.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replacing "localhost" with the actual IP address of the box? In other words, both lists should look like this:

.set("locators", "10.0.0.192[11001],10.0.0.193[11002]")

I believe the locator by default binds to the public IP address of your machine, not localhost (127.0.0.1).

Comment: this is not working for me also.  i dont get a cluster.